# How to log raw HTTP request/response in Python FastAPI?

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, python-logging, starlette

We are writing a web service using Python FastAPI that is going to be hosted in Kubernetes. For auditing purposes, we need to save the raw JSON body of the `request`/`response` for **specific** routes. The body size of both `request` and `response` JSON is about **1MB**, and preferably, this should not impact the response time.
How can we do that?

Comment: Related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400683/python-logging-with-loguru-log-request-params-on-fastapi-app) You could use middleware or apirouter and [loguru](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#loguru._logger.Logger) logger with option `enqueue=True`. This will allow you not to affect response time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to customize [APIRouter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/#custom-apiroute-class-in-a-router) like in FastAPI official documentation:

```py
import time
from typing import Callable

from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute


class TimedRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            before = time.time()
            response: Response = await original_route_handler(request)
            duration = time.time() - before
            response.headers["X-Response-Time"] = str(duration)
            print(f"route duration: {duration}")
            print(f"route response: {response}")
            print(f"route response headers: {response.headers}")
            return response

        return custom_route_handler


app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter(route_class=TimedRoute)


@app.get("/")
async def not_timed():
    return {"message": "Not timed"}


@router.get("/timed")
async def timed():
    return {"message": "It's the time of my life"}


app.include_router(router)
```

Answer (score 41):

## Option 1 - Using Middleware

You could use a [`Middleware`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/). A `middleware` takes each request that comes to your application, and hence, allows you to handle the `request` before it is processed by any specific endpoint, as well as the `response`, before it is returned to the client. To create a `middleware`, you use the decorator `@app.middleware("http")` on top of a function, as shown below.

As you need to consume the request body from the stream inside the `middleware`—using either `request.body()` or `request.stream()`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72062813/17865804) (behind the scenes, the former method actually calls the latter, see [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/bd219edc4571806edf80fd6a48c8ac3fbbadcf22/starlette/requests.py#L231))—then it won't be available when you later pass the `request` to the corresponding endpoint. Thus, you can follow the approach described in [this post](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/495#issuecomment-513138055) to make the request body available down the line (i.e., using the `set_body()` function below). **UPDATE:** This [issue has now been fixed](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/8187#discussioncomment-7962889), and hence, there is no need to use that workaround, if you are using FastAPI 0.108.0 or later versions.

As for the `response` body, you can use the same approach as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71883126/17865804) to consume the body and then return the `response` to the client. Either option described in the aforementioned linked answer would work; the below, however, uses Option 2, which stores the body in a bytes object and returns a custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response) directly (along with the `status_code`, `headers` and `media_type` of the original `response`).

To log the data, you could use a [`BackgroundTask`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283272/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70899261/17865804) and [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152/17865804) A `BackgroundTask` will run only once the response has been sent (see [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/background/) as well); thus, the client won't have to be waiting for the logging to complete before receiving the `response` (and hence, the response time won't be noticeably impacted).

#### Note

If you had a streaming `request` or `response` with a body that wouldn't fit into your server's RAM (for example, imagine a body of 100GB on a machine running 8GB RAM), it would become problematic, as you are storing the data to RAM, which wouldn't have enough space available to accommodate the accumulated data. Also, in case of a large `response` (e.g., a large `FileResponse` or `StreamingResponse`), you may be faced with `Timeout` errors on client side (or on reverse proxy side, if you are using one), as you would not be able to respond back to the client, until you have read the entire response body (as you are looping over `response.body_iterator`). You mentioned that *"the body size of both request and response JSON is about 1MB"*; hence, that should normally be fine (however, it is always a good practice to consider beforehand matters, such as how many requests your API is expected to be serving concurrently, what other applications might be using the RAM, etc., in order to rule whether this is an issue or not). If you needed to, you could limit the number of requests to your API endpoints using, for example, [SlowAPI](https://github.com/laurentS/slowapi) (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183527/17865804)).

#### Limiting the usage of the `middleware` to specific routes only

You could limit the usage of the `middleware` to specific endpoints by:

- checking the `request.url.path` inside the middleware against a
  pre-defined list of routes for which you would like to log the
  `request` and `response`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71107848/17865804) (see
  "**Update**" section),
- or using a [sub application](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/#sub-applications-mounts), as demonstrated in [this
  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75048778/17865804)
- or using a custom `APIRoute` class, as demonstrated in **Option 2**
  below.

#### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Response, Request
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute
from starlette.types import Message
from typing import Dict, Any
import logging


app = FastAPI()
logging.basicConfig(filename='info.log', level=logging.DEBUG)


def log_info(req_body, res_body):
    logging.info(req_body)
    logging.info(res_body)


# not needed when using FastAPI>=0.108.0.
async def set_body(request: Request, body: bytes):
    async def receive() -> Message:
        return {'type': 'http.request', 'body': body}
    request._receive = receive


@app.middleware('http')
async def some_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    req_body = await request.body()
    await set_body(request, req_body)  # not needed when using FastAPI>=0.108.0.
    response = await call_next(request)
    
    res_body = b''
    async for chunk in response.body_iterator:
        res_body += chunk
    
    task = BackgroundTask(log_info, req_body, res_body)
    return Response(content=res_body, status_code=response.status_code, 
        headers=dict(response.headers), media_type=response.media_type, background=task)


@app.post('/')
def main(payload: Dict[Any, Any]):
    return payload
```

In case you would like to perform some validation on the request body—for example, ensruing that the request body size is not exceeding a certain value—instead of using `request.body()`, you can process the body one chunk at a time using the `.stream()` method, as shown below (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804)).

```py
@app.middleware('http')
async def some_middleware(request: Request, call_next):    
    req_body = b''
    async for chunk in request.stream():
        req_body += chunk
    ...
```

## Option 2 - Using custom `APIRoute` class

You can alternatively use a [custom  `APIRoute` class](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/#custom-apiroute-class-in-a-router)—similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74262037/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804)—which, among other things, would allow you to manipulate the `request` body before it is processed by your application, as well as the `response` body before it is returned to the client. This option also allows you to limit the usage of this class to the routes you wish, as only the endpoints under the [`APIRouter`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#apirouter) (i.e., `router` in the example below) will use the custom `APIRoute` class .

It should be noted that the same comments mentioned in **Option 1** above, under the "**Note**" section, apply to this option as well. For example, if your API returns a `StreamingResponse`—such as in `/video` route of the example below, which is [streaming a video file from an online source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804) (public videos to test this can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jsturgis/3b19447b304616f18657), and you can even use a longer video than the one used below to see the effect more clearly)—you may come across issues on server side, if your server's RAM can't handle it, as well as delays on client side (and reverse proxy server, if using one) due to the whole (streaming) response being read and stored in RAM, before it is returned to the client (as explained earlier). In such cases, you could exclude such endpoints that return a `StreamingResponse` from the custom `APIRoute` class and limit its usage only to the desired routes—especially, if it is a large video file, or even live video that wouldn't likely make much sense to have it stored in the logs—simply by not using the `@<name_of_router>` decorator (i.e.,  `@router` in the example below) for such endpoints, but rather using the `@<name_of_app>` decorator (i.e., `@app` in the example below), or some other [`APIRouter`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#apirouter) or [sub application](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/#sub-applications-mounts).

#### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Response, Request
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask
from starlette.responses import StreamingResponse
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute
from starlette.types import Message
from typing import Callable, Dict, Any
import logging
import httpx


def log_info(req_body, res_body):
    logging.info(req_body)
    logging.info(res_body)

       
class LoggingRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            req_body = await request.body()
            response = await original_route_handler(request)
            tasks = response.background
            
            if isinstance(response, StreamingResponse):
                res_body = b''
                async for item in response.body_iterator:
                    res_body += item
                  
                task = BackgroundTask(log_info, req_body, res_body)
                response = Response(content=res_body, status_code=response.status_code, 
                        headers=dict(response.headers), media_type=response.media_type)
            else:
                task = BackgroundTask(log_info, req_body, response.body)
            
            # check if the original response had background tasks already attached to it
            if tasks:
                tasks.add_task(task)  # add the new task to the tasks list
                response.background = tasks
            else:
                response.background = task
                
            return response
            
        return custom_route_handler


app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter(route_class=LoggingRoute)
logging.basicConfig(filename='info.log', level=logging.DEBUG)


@router.post('/')
def main(payload: Dict[Any, Any]):
    return payload


@router.get('/video')
def get_video():
    url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4'
    
    def gen():
        with httpx.stream('GET', url) as r:
            for chunk in r.iter_raw():
                yield chunk

    return StreamingResponse(gen(), media_type='video/mp4')


app.include_router(router)
```

Comment: Option 1 works fine when a FastAPI request works OK. But the code is not executed when something goes wrong and a HTTP Exception like 'HTTPException(400, str(e))` is raised. How can I log the incoming request in these cases, too?

Comment: @576i I had a quick look and the code works as expected, even when `HTTPException` is raised.

Comment: yes there was a problem with my code. Thanks for taking a look.

BTW, I have not found a way to quickly see which of the router's endpoint was triggered plus have a way to bubble up information from the endpoint. Currently I misuse the response headers to pass values upwards to the logger, but that seems like a dirty hack to me.

Comment: @576i You could use `request.url.path`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75729917/17865804), to identify which endpoint was triggered. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72239186/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74262037/17865804) as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and it works. (but it seems not suitable for larger projects) In my real world code I have the routes in seperate files with are imported and attached like this `app.include_router(router=routes_status.router, prefix="/api", tags=["My API"])`. These routers has a few endpoints each. For me the obvious place to store the info if something should trigger the middleware is in that file close to the endpoint, so the should-I-log info should "bubble up". That's why I am passing the info up via headers, but am looking for a better way. I should make that a new question...

Comment: @576i You could store additional information on the `Request` object using `request.state`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105859/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804). You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804) helpful as well.

Comment: thanks for those suggestions - that's very helpful.

Comment: If using `fastapi>0.106.0` then you no longer need the `set_body()` method described above in Option 1. If you try to use it, then you will get error `Unexpected message received: http.request`. This is because this 'quirk' of fastapi has been fixed, so you no longer need to restore the request body after reading it. See more at https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/8187#discussioncomment-7962881

Comment: @ZoltanFedor The answer has been updated with the relevant details. Couldn't reproduce the error you mentioned though - the example worked as expected even with using the `set_body()` method (in FastAPI 0.108.0). Regardless, since the issue has now been fixed, there is no longer need for calling the `set_body()` method.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers did not work for me and I searched quite extensively on stackoverflow to fix this problem, I will show my solution below.

The main issue is that when using the request body or response body many of the approaches/solutions offered online do simply not work as the request/response body is consumed in reading it from the stream.

To solve this issue I adapted an approach that basically reconstructs the request and response after reading them. This is heavily based on the comment by user 'kovalevvlad' on https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/495.

Custom middleware is created that is later added to the app to log all requests and responses. Note that you need some kind of logger to store your logs.

```
from json import JSONDecodeError
import json
import logging
from typing import Callable, Awaitable, Tuple, Dict, List

from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import Response, StreamingResponse
from starlette.types import Scope, Message

# Set up your custom logger here
logger = ""

class RequestWithBody(Request):
    """Creation of new request with body"""
    def __init__(self, scope: Scope, body: bytes) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, self._receive)
        self._body = body
        self._body_returned = False

    async def _receive(self) -> Message:
        if self._body_returned:
            return {"type": "http.disconnect"}
        else:
            self._body_returned = True
            return {"type": "http.request", "body": self._body, "more_body": False}


class CustomLoggingMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    """
    Use of custom middleware since reading the request body and the response consumes the bytestream.
    Hence this approach to basically generate a new request/response when we read the attributes for logging.
    """
    async def dispatch(  # type: ignore
        self, request: Request, call_next: Callable[[Request], Awaitable[StreamingResponse]]
    ) -> Response:
            # Store request body in a variable and generate new request as it is consumed.
            request_body_bytes = await request.body()
        
        request_with_body = RequestWithBody(request.scope, request_body_bytes)

        # Store response body in a variable and generate new response as it is consumed.
        response = await call_next(request_with_body)
        response_content_bytes, response_headers, response_status = await self._get_response_params(response)

        # Logging

        # If there is no request body handle exception, otherwise convert bytes to JSON.
        try:
            req_body = json.loads(request_body_bytes)
        except JSONDecodeError:
            req_body = ""
        # Logging of relevant variables.
        logger.info(
            f"{request.method} request to {request.url} metadata\n"
            f"\tStatus_code: {response.status_code}\n"
            f"\tRequest_Body: {req_body}\n"
        )
        # Finally, return the newly instantiated response values
        return Response(response_content_bytes, response_status, response_headers)

async def _get_response_params(self, response: StreamingResponse) -> Tuple[bytes, Dict[str, str], int]:
    """Getting the response parameters of a response and create a new response."""
    response_byte_chunks: List[bytes] = []
    response_status: List[int] = []
    response_headers: List[Dict[str, str]] = []

    async def send(message: Message) -> None:
        if message["type"] == "http.response.start":
            response_status.append(message["status"])
            response_headers.append({k.decode("utf8"): v.decode("utf8") for k, v in message["headers"]})
        else:
            response_byte_chunks.append(message["body"])

    await response.stream_response(send)
    content = b"".join(response_byte_chunks)
    return content, response_headers[0], response_status[0]
```

Comment: Thanks Jan! You saved me a lot of effort.

Comment: As a note to this example, and the others - all sharing some similarities around recreating the original response: these all contain a bug where duplicate response headers (which are allowed per http spec, e.g. multiple set-cookie headers) will be removed, and only the last one will be kept. This happens due to the List[Tuple[bytes, bytes]] -> Dict[str, str] conversion.