# FastAPI and SlowAPI limit request under all “path/*”

Tags: python, fastapi, slowapi

I'm having a problem with SlowAPI. All requests are limited according to the middleware, but I cannot manage to jointly limit all requests under the path `/schools/`

My code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, status
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from slowapi import Limiter, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler
from slowapi.util import get_remote_address
from slowapi.errors import RateLimitExceeded
from slowapi.middleware import SlowAPIMiddleware

limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address, default_limits=["2/5seconds"])
app = FastAPI()
app.state.limiter = limiter
app.add_exception_handler(RateLimitExceeded, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler)

origins = ["http://127.0.0.1/", "http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.75"] ## CORS

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
app.add_middleware(SlowAPIMiddleware) ## Rate-limit all request

@app.get('/schools/{regione}/{provincia}/{comune}')
def search_school(request: Request, response: Response, regione: str, provincia: str, comune: str):
        return {"message": 'No schools found!', "status": 'error', "code": 200} ## Or if found return schools informations

@app.get('/testpath/{regione}') ## Works with one path. If I add "provincia" and "comune" non work
def search_school(request: Request, response: Response, regione: str, provincia: str, comune: str):
        return {"message": 'No schools found!', "status": 'error', "code": 200} ## Or if found return schools informations
```

When i send a request to `/schools/{region}/{province}/{city}` with jQuery the whole url is limited and therefore if I change region or province the limits are reset. How can I make myself apply settings for `/schools/*`

Example:

*2 request every 5 seconds*

If i send to request to `apiURL+/schools/Lombardy/Milan/Milan` the limit increases by 1 and if i made anothe 2 request at the third I get blocked.

But if instead of making it to the same domain, I change the city (`apiURL+/schools/Sicily/Palermo/Palermo`), the limit resets and returns to 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1

Define `application_limits` when instantiating the `Limiter` class, as shown below. As per the [documentation](https://slowapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/),

> **application_limits**:
> a variable list of strings or callables returning strings for limits
> that are applied to the entire application (i.e., a shared limit for all
> routes)

Thus, the below would apply a shared limit to all `/schools/*` routes, as well as any other route that might be in your application (e.g., `/testpath/*`, `/some-other-route/`, and so on), meaning that, only two requests per 5 seconds would go through by each client (regardless of the endpoint they would call).

```
limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address, application_limits=["2/5seconds"])
```

### Option 2

Apply a shared limit only to the endpoints you wish, using `shared_limit`.  As per the [documentation](https://slowapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/):

> **shared_limit**: Decorator to be applied to multiple routes sharing the same rate limit.

Thus, the below would apply a shared limit only to `/schools/*` routes.

```
limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address, default_limits=["2/5seconds"])

@app.get('/schools/{regione}/{provincia}/{comune}')
@limiter.shared_limit(limit_value="2/5seconds", scope="schools") 
def search_school(request: Request, response: Response, regione: str, provincia: str, comune: str):
        return {"message": 'No schools found!', "status": 'error', "code": 200}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this afternoon I try both solutions.

Comment: Both option work. Thanks!

Comment: What if I wanted to set more limits? Like 1 per second and 10 per minute?

Comment: If you are using the first option, you could use, for example, `application_limits=["2/5seconds", "10/minute"]`. If the second option is used, you could define multiple rate limit rules separated by `;`, e.g.,  `limit_value="2/5seconds; 10/minute"`, or using multiple decorators (one for each rule).

Comment: a thousand thanks. In my case I used the second option