# FastAPI modify request model before parsing based on header

Tags: fastapi

I have an immutable Pydantic model (`Item`) that requires a field `shape_mode` that is `schematic` or `realistic`. The default value of the `shape_mode` should depend on the response class:

- for `application/json` default is `schematic`
- for `image/png` default is `realistic`

The question is: can I modify the field `shape_mode` based on the `accept` header, before the body is parsed to an `Item` object?

```py
from enum import Enum

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ShapeModeEnum(str, Enum):
    schematic = "schematic"
    realistic = "realistic"


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    shape_mode: ShapeModeEnum

    class Config:
        allow_mutation = False
        extra = "forbid"
        strict = True
        validate_assignment = True


app = FastAPI()

RESPONSE_CLASSES = {
    "application/json": "schematic",
    "image/png": "realistic",
}


@app.post("/item")
async def create_item(
    request: Request,
    item: Item,
):
    accept = request.headers["accept"]
    return [item, accept]
```

Comment: You could use a middleware to modify the body as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804).

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. If you require an `Item` in a request body (in your example, `shape_mode` is a required field), why do you want to mutate it later on when FastAPI is parsing it?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by combining a couple of concepts; inheriting BaseModels and dependencies. Below is a working example (although not really robust; it will throw HTTP500 if you try to post a request with a non-valid `accept` header.

```
from enum import Enum

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class ShapeModeEnum(str, Enum):
    schematic = "schematic"
    realistic = "realistic"


class ItemBase(BaseModel):
    name: str


class Item(ItemBase):
    shape_mode: ShapeModeEnum

    class Config:
        # allow_mutation = False
        extra = "forbid"
        strict = True
        validate_assignment = True


def get_real_item(request: Request, item: ItemBase) -> Item:
    RESPONSE_CLASSES = {"application/json": "schematic", "image/png": "realistic"}

    return Item(
        name=item.name, shape_mode=RESPONSE_CLASSES[request.headers.get("Accept", None)]
    )


@app.post("/item")
async def get_item(item: Item = Depends(get_real_item)):
    return item


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"hello": "world"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Calling with curl:

```
% curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8000/item' \
  -H 'accept: image/png' \ 
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "string"
}'
{"name":"string","shape_mode":"realistic"}%

% curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8000/item' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "string"
}'
{"name":"string","shape_mode":"schematic"}%
```