# How to cache data in FastAPI?

Tags: python, caching, fastapi, cache-control

How can I cache requests in FastAPI?

For example, there are two functions and a PostgreSQL database:

```py
@app.get("/")
def home(request: Request):
  return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})


@app.post("/api/getData")
async def getData(request: Request, databody = Body()):
  data = databody ['data']
  
  with connection.cursor() as cursor:
       cursor.execute(
              f'INSER INTO database (ip, useragent, datetime) VALUES ('request.headers['host']', 'request.headers['user-agent']', '{datetime.now()}')
       )
   return {'req': request}
```

Then the request is processed by JavaScript and displayed on the HTML page
.

Comment: Generally http caching should live outside of the web application for scalability - i.e. do caching in nginx or varnish or something else. Let your application send `Cache-Control`-headers that the reverse proxy/cache server respects. That way those requests will never even hit your API in any way, meaning that FastAPI will never see them unless when necessary (usually when a POST request happens).

Comment: Future readers looking for how to log an HTTP request/response in FastAPI instead, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [fastapi-cache](https://github.com/long2ice/fastapi-cache):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import Response
    
from fastapi_cache import FastAPICache
from fastapi_cache.backends.redis import RedisBackend
from fastapi_cache.decorator import cache
    
from redis import asyncio as aioredis
    
app = FastAPI()
    
    
@cache()
async def get_cache():
    return 1
    
    
@app.get("/")
@cache(expire=60)
async def index():
    return dict(hello="world")
    
    
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
   redis = aioredis.from_url("redis://localhost", encoding="utf8", decode_responses=True)
   FastAPICache.init(RedisBackend(redis), prefix="fastapi-cache")
```

Comment: How do I initialise MemcachedBackend, to use memcache

Comment: This package has a MemcachedBackend too. You can check it out here at the source repo: https://github.com/long2ice/fastapi-cache.