# How to reuse interim data in 2 different rest api endpoints?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I have 2 different endpoints

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/endpoint_1")
async def endpoint_1(attributes):
    interim_data = await get_interim_data() # performs heavy search
    result = process_data_1(interim_data)
    return result


@router.get("/endpoint_2")
async def endpoint_2():
    interim_data = await get_interim_data() # performs heavy search
    result = process_data_2(interim_data)
    return result
```

Both endpoints call the same function to get initial data but further usage of that data is different. If requests to `endpoint_1` and `endpoint_2` are created at the same time, how can I make it so that `get_interim_data` would only be called once?

Comment: You can cache the result, look it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74360992/how-to-cache-data-in-fastapi

Comment: You can calculate your data once [on startup](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#startup-event) and store the result in global scope variable

Comment: @HenriqueAndrade I don't think cache will help as `get_interim_data` will be called in both endpoints before it is stored in cache

Comment: @sudden_appearance `get_interim_data` depends on parameters passed, so it is not possible to precalculate

Comment: Do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71188190/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) answer your question?