# fastapi - how to use middleware to change the request body?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I know i can create a middleware function using the `@app.middleware("http")` annotation.

I would like to create such function, that before every POST request, will modify the request body in a way.

I know the generic structure is of this form:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def middleware_function_example(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response
```

But how can i modify the request body?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom ASGI middleware class to modify the request body, here is an example:

```py
import json

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


app = FastAPI()


class Value(BaseModel):
    value: str


class CustomMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        if scope["type"] != "http":
            await self.app(scope, receive, send)
            return

        async def modify_body():
            message = await receive()
            assert message["type"] == "http.request"

            body: bytes = message.get("body", b"")
            body: str = body.decode()
            data = json.loads(body)
            data["value"] = "456"

            message["body"] = json.dumps(data).encode()
            return message

        await self.app(scope, modify_body, send)


app.add_middleware(CustomMiddleware)


@app.post("/test", response_model=dict)
def test(value: Value):
    return value.dict()
```

Calling the endpoint we can see that the update body is passed to the function:

```py
url = f'http://localhost:8000/test'
response = requests.post(url, json={"value": "123"})
response.status_code, response.json()
>>> (200, {'value': '456'})
```

See also the [starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/middleware/).

Comment: do i have access to the request header as well? (edit, i believe its accessible from scope)

Comment: Yes it is accessible from `scope`